# VSTS Get ID of Stored Queries

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to execute a VSTS stored query using `WorkItemTrackingHttpClient`

The stored query is identified by it's ID and there are code samples to programmatically get this ID. However, I can't seem to figure out how I can get this ID within VSTS online view. Clicking on the query lists the workitems returned bye this query but the query ID isn't listed anywhere. Is this due to privileges of my authentication or I am overlooking something.

Comment: What's the actual URL once clicking a query? Is there id parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the query ID in the URL:

1. Select a query
2. The URL format will be like: `https://[xxx].visualstudio.com/[project]/_queries?id=effb4d62-1b9b-42e9-af7c-dbef725fca4a&_a=query`.
3. The id is the value of id parameter.

Comment: I see, so what would I pass as parameter to .QueryByIdAsync. It expects a Guid, how can I instantiate a Guid object using this id?

Comment: I figured out through instinct that I can pass the id parameter when constructing the Guid object for the query.